# Is there any way to build below using UDF in snowflake instead of flattening?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

i have below tables
table1:
Payload(column)

```
{
"list": "212=1.00,214"
}
```

table 2 looks like below

[image: table2]

i want result like below using UDF instead of using flatten

```
{
  "test13": {
    "code": "212",
    "desc": "success",
    "value": "1.00"
  },
  "test15": {
    "code": "214",
    "desc": "Impression",
    "value": ""
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You ought to be able to do JavaScript UDTFs (User-Defined Table Functions) https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/udf-js-table-functions.html that can take the single row payload and return multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

So the SQL to do this, I understand you don't want:

```
with table1 AS (               
  select parse_json('{"list": "212=1.00,214"}') as payload
), table2 AS (
  select parse_json(column1) as payload
    ,column2 as key
    ,column3 as value
  from values ('{"id":"212"}', 'test13', 'success' ),
              ('{"id":"214"}', 'test15', 'impression' )
), table1_demunged AS (
  select split(f.value,'=')[0] as id
    ,split(f.value,'=')[1] as val
  from table1 t, lateral flatten(input=>split(t.payload:list,',')) f
), tables_joined as (
  select t2.key as obj_key
    ,t1.id as code
    ,t2.value as desc
    ,t1.val as value
  from table2 t2
  join table1_demunged t1 on t2.payload:id = t1.id
), as_objects AS (
    select obj_key, object_construct('code', code, 'desc', desc, 'value', coalesce(value,'')) as res
    from tables_joined t
)
select object_agg(obj_key, res) object
from as_objects
group by true;
```

gives the result you do want:

```
OBJECT
{    "test13": {      "code": "212",      "desc": "success",      "value": "1.00"    },    "test15": {      "code": "214",      "desc": "impression",      "value": ""    }  }
```

But I do not understand if your are really want a UDF to do all that, given it's a FLATTEN then a JOIN and then some OBJECT_ functions, or if you are just want to avoid the FALTTEN as it "tricky SQL and you want to find it behind a UDF" or perhaps your using some system that cannot parse the `=>` thus you need the flatten hidden behind a UDF, but in that case the UDF cannot do all the joins for you..

It just feels like there is more to the question than has been asked.